# Count Cell if value in Column A is 1

Tags: excel, formula

I'm looking to get my formula to work. I want it to count how many cells in column G contain 6/7/8, but only if the cell in Column A contains a 1.

That is what I currently have.

```
{=SUM(IF(A4:A72=1,1,0) AND IF(G4:G72="6/7/8",1,0))}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a count, using Countifs will be helpful.  Since it's a simple comparison on cell A1, I'd put it in an If statement like so:

```
=IF(A1=1,COUNTIFS(G:G,"6/7/8"),FALSE)
```